# How can I understand an alert of "cpverify" will damage your computer?

Tags: macos, malware

I got this alert that has me concerned.

If I click Ok, then it appear again. File located here: `opt/cprocsp/bin/`.
[image]

After installing the latest OS update all files in that folder has a prefix `corrupted.`
[image]

Should I wipe my laptop and reinstall OS?

Answer (score 9):

> What is this?

This is utility associated with CryptoPro app (digital signature app, accepted by Russian government and tax office) which was normally located in `/opt/cprocsp`.

Apple rejected their dev cert due to US sanctions, so it's not running on MacOS anymore. See "LIMITED LIABILITY COMPANY CRYPTO PRO" in the recent sanctions list: https://ofac.treasury.gov/recent-actions/20240223.

You can follow official CryptoPro support for the updates on that issue.

> Should I wipe my laptop and reinstall OS?

No, the utility was safe to use, but now it won't even launch no matter what you do (I even tried to bypass quarantine - still doesn't work).

I believe you can just delete it manually to avoid annoying popup.

Comment: Reinstall updated Crypto Pro version 5.0.12998 https://support.cryptopro.ru/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/455/8/ustnovk-kriptopro-csp-n-macos-posle-blokirovki